# Add lines below rows dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have written this code to send an email when an change is made in a gridview.

I send an email with changes made in the column in row format. I need to add a line below each row and I am using this code and it doesn't work.

I have used this part to add line below rows `sbMsg.AppendFormat("<table rules=" + rows + " style=' font-family:Calibri;background-color:#F1F1F1' width='1000'>");`

```
public string mailFormatting(string Code)
    {
        List<string> lstSpecificColumns = new List<string>();
        DataTable dtCurrentTbl = activeApplication.LoadMailActiveApplications(Code.ToString().Trim());
        DataTable dtOldTbl = activeApplication.LoadMailLogManualUpdatesDetails(Code.ToString().Trim());

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < dtCurrentTbl.Columns.Count; colIndex++)
        {
            if (!dtCurrentTbl.Rows[0][colIndex].ToString().Equals(dtOldTbl.Rows[0][colIndex].ToString()))
            {
                lstSpecificColumns.Add(dtCurrentTbl.Columns[colIndex].ColumnName);
            }
        }

        dtCurrentTbl.Merge(dtOldTbl);
        DataTable resultTbl = dtCurrentTbl.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable().DefaultView.ToTable(true, lstSpecificColumns.ToArray());

        string rows = "\"rows\"";            
        StringBuilder sbMsg = new StringBuilder();
        sbMsg.AppendFormat("<p><font color=gray>Title<font></p>");
        sbMsg.AppendFormat("<table rules= + rows +  style='font-family:Calibri;background-color:#F1F1F1' width='1000'>");      
        sbMsg.AppendFormat("<tr> <td colspan='2'> <font color=blue> <u> " + Code.ToString().Trim() + " </u></font><td></tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in resultTbl.Columns)
        {
            sbMsg.AppendFormat("<tr>");
            sbMsg.AppendFormat("<td> " + dc.ColumnName.Trim() + "   </td>");
            sbMsg.AppendFormat("<td> <strike>" + resultTbl.Rows[1][dc].ToString().Trim() + "</strike>" + " " + resultTbl.Rows[0][dc].ToString().Trim() + "  </td>");
            sbMsg.AppendFormat("</tr>");
        }
        sbMsg.AppendFormat("</table>");
        return sbMsg.ToString();
    }
```

Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Just a small note that using string builder and passing there concatenated string is not the best idea - AppendFormat("<table rules=" + rows + ".... Check usage there - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ok so then how can I achieve this?

Comment: something like that .AppendFormat("text {0}", rows)

Comment: So what exactly is not working. Do you get any error or wrong result?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but not able to add lines below rows.

Comment: Hard to say what exactly is wrong without knowing about your **resultTbl**. So are you saying that you getting just table with one row (with font color blue) if so that only could mean that your resultTbl has no Columns

Comment: so you mean the line should be like this `sbMsg.AppendFormat("text {0}", rows)` instead of `sbMsg.AppendFormat("<table rules=" + rows + " style=' font-family:Calibri;background-color:#F1F1F1' width='1000'>");`. But my question is how can we add line without even using the table.
`

Comment: @Vladimirs - Updated my code. Please take a look.

Comment: line `sbMsg.AppendFormat("<table rules=" + rows + " style=' font-family:Calibri;background-color:#F1F1F1' width='1000'>");` should be like `sbMsg.AppendFormat("<table rules={0} style=' font-family:Calibri;background-color:#F1F1F1' width='1000'>", rows);` - but that is off-topic - just pointed you to a better practice.But regarding to your question can you be please more concrete: adding line to where (to your html table?), without using table(which one? resultTbl)

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't add line below rows.

Comment: So what are you currently getting? Just 1 row? No rows?

Comment: @Vladimirs - I am getting row, but not getting the line below the rows.